# Telegram-bot. Как сделать вывод новых кнопок при нажатии на предыдущую кнопку в меню. РyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Как в боте pyTelegramBotAPI сделать так чтобы он выводил кнопки и а при нажатии на одну из них бот выводил другие кнопки
О ком хочешь узнать :

- кнопка 1
- кнопка 2

при нажатии на кнопку 1, один список людей

а при нажатии на кнопку 2, другой список людей

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии на кнопку в телеграмме его **inline keyboard callback_data**.

Отлавливаешь её, получаешь её значение и в соответствии с ним вызываешь нужную функцию

https://core.telegram.org/constructor/keyboardButtonCallback